# Help me refactor my admin user views vs. non admin user views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have a list of books that displays edit buttons and a bunch of extra info if the user that's logged in is an admin.  Right now I have two separate partials that are rendered depending on what type of user is logged in.  I used to have just one partial with a bunch of if user.admin? statements, but it started to get real ugly.  Now I am juggling around two files, with little bits of duplicate data in each.  Is there any better way to do this?

index.html.erb

```
<ul>
  <% if @current_user.admin? %>
    <%= render :partial => "book", :collection => @books %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render :partial => "non_admin_book", :collection => @books %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

_book.html.erb

```
Title: <%= book.title %> EDIT BUTTON
<!-- Awesome extra info for admins -->
Author: <%= book.author %>
<!-- Awesome extra info for admins -->
```

_non_adminbook.html.erb

```
Title: <%= book.title %>
Author: <%= book.author %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is like : should I only use I18n keys all over one partial/view or should I use X views/partials for each language ?

There is no good or bad solution. My opinion is that you should begin by using conditionals like <% if admin? %> blah blah <% end %>...

Then, if your admin view grandly differs from your non admin views, delete the conditionals and make two views : my_view / my_view_admin.

Answer (score 2):

[#192 Authorization with CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)  this cancan gem may help you

Answer (score 2):

I really do not like any kind of duplication, but sometimes it is the easiest solution.

In your case, I can tell that

- an administrator has the option to edit fields (inline?)
- an administrator sees more fields

Generally I use the [on_the_spot](https://github.com/nathanvda/on_the_spot) gem for inline editing, and I then work with a helper like this:

```
def on_the_spot_edit_if_allowed(object, field, options)
  if current_user.admin?
    on_the_spot_edit object, field, options
  else
    object.send(field)
  end
end
```

And in that case my views becomes something like

```
Title: <%= on_the_spot_edit_if_allowed book, title %>
<%- if current_user.admin? %>
  <!-- Awesome extra info for admins -->
<% end %>
Author: <%= book.author %>
<%- if current_user.admin? %>
  <!-- Awesome extra info for admins -->
<% end %>
```

Unless it is otherwise (design/UI constraints) impossible, I would refactor that view to the following:

```
Title: <%= on_the_spot_edit_if_allowed book, title %>
Author: <%= book.author %>
<%- if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= render :partial => 'extra_admin_fields'
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Keep it like it is.**

Your duplications are not that big.

The `@current_user.admin?` condition will be run only once with your solution.

If you put `@current_user.admin?` in a shared partial, it will be run for *every single member of this collection*. Not cool.